# What is the difference between Desiredcapabilities & Chromeoptions and when to use them?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I am relatively new to selenium webdriver.

I wanted to know what is the main difference between Desiredcapabilities vs Chromeoptions?

In which situation to use them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link will answer your question](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).
Basically, it says:

Capabilities are options that you can use to customize and configure a ChromeDriver session. This page documents all ChromeDriver supported capabilities and how to use them.

There are two ways to specify capabilities.

1. The first is to use the ChromeOptions class.
2. If your client library does not have a ChromeOptions class (like the selenium ruby client), you can specify the capabilities directly as part of the DesiredCapabilities.